# Laravel put contents in php file?

Tags: php, laravel

I've got an error in a Laravel instance, which says:

> [2016-11-08 16:48:19] prod.ERROR: ErrorException:
>   file_put_contents(/theLaravelSite/bootstrap/cache/services.php):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /theLaravelSite/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:7327

I've seen these errors before, which relate to the `storage` folder, but I'm a bit confused by this one, since it seems to say that it tries to write content to `bootstrap/cache/services.php`.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Change the directory permissions to:

```
chmod -R 775 storage/
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache/
```

According to [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/)

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the **Homestead** virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

Answer (score 2):

You should set correct permissions on `bootstrap` folder recursively:

```
chmod -R 775 bootstrap
```

Also, check if `bootstrap/cache` exists. If it doesn't exist, create it manually.